# Powershell conditionally add switch & parameter to function call

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am using a function that has an optional switch, however in a loop, switch and related value may be required or not, depending on a pagination mechanism.

```
# basic function call
myFunction $someParam 

# function call with pagination switch
myFunction $someParam -NextPageToken $theToken
```

Ideally this should be used in a more elegant way in a loop:

```
$theToken = ""
do{
   $result = myFunction $someParam -NextPageToken $theToken # pagination switch should not be used on first call
   $theToken = $result.next_page_token
}while($theToken -ne "")
```

But the function will throw an error if the switch is used with no value....

Does Powershell support dynamically/conditionally adding the switch & value only if required, so that the function call is used only once in code?

Comment: Does not sound like a good function design. Let it return the first token when `""` is passed to `-NextPageToken` or don't use any parameter and just let it return the next token (works only if you don't need to go back).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a hashtable to splat the token:

```bsh
$params = @{}
do{
   $result = myFunction $someParam @params
   $params = @{ NextPageToken = $result.next_page_token }
}while("" -ne $params['NextPageToken'])
```

On the first iteration, the splatting table will be empty (ie. no `NextPageToken` parameter will be passed), but subsequent runs will.

See the [`about_Splatting` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to learn more about using splatting for conditional parameter arguments

Comment: Stylish!......... Thanks :-) . Just a question: in your sample, is it intentional to use `NextPageToken ` in place of `-NextPageToken ` ?

Comment: @Riccardo Yes that's intentional - the hashtable key must match the _name_ of the parameter - and the `-` we use in normal command syntax is not part of the name itself